# JQuery slider not showing in IE and Chrome, but showing on FF

Tags: jquery, magento

I downloaded a jQuery slider from dynamicdrive.com and embeded it into my site. It has the ability to play, pause, forward and previous scroll the pictures. It was working fine before on all three browsers, but it wasn't showing the icons for controlling the slider.

So I declared a variable in the head, and assigned them the path of each picture. Then, I called those variables instead of pictures. Now it is showing on Firefox, but not on any other browser. The slider is on left side after the login form on [my site](http://www.allinonesolutionz.com).

Answer (score 1):

you can bet for jQuery and Prototype conflict as magento uses Prototype and they both bind to $ as their method name

Comment: i had already replaced "$" with "jQuery" and is working fine in FireFox.

Comment: ie has a javascript debugger console , use this to diagnose the "not working" situation